# Most efficient way for a nested sql server update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I am going to update a table using the sum of specific value from 3 different tables. For this purpose I wrote this query. But it takes too much time, what is the most efficient query for this purpose?

```
UPDATE dbo.dumpfile_doroud 
SET    dumpfile_doroud.sms_count_on_net = (SELECT sms_count_on_net 
                                           FROM   dbo.dumpfile139201 
                                           WHERE 
              dbo.dumpfile_doroud.msisdn = dbo.dumpfile139201.msisdn) 
                                          + (SELECT sms_count_on_net 
                                             FROM   dbo.dumpfile139202 
                                             WHERE 
              dbo.dumpfile_doroud.msisdn = dbo.dumpfile139202.msisdn) 
                                          + (SELECT sms_count_on_net 
                                             FROM   dbo.dumpfile139203 
                                             WHERE 
              dbo.dumpfile_doroud.msisdn = dbo.dumpfile139203.msisdn)
```

P.S: dumpfile_doroud is small table but other three tables are really big.

Comment: is there a way to make that one visible chunk? rather than horiz. scroll?

Comment: ok nevernmind. thanks Fresh!!

Comment: This is very likely a problem caused by an absence of appropriate indexes.  We will need to see what indexes you have on all four tables.  And/Or the query plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.sms_count_on_net=isnull(t2.sms_count_on_net,0) + 
                        isnull(t3.sms_count_on_net,0) + 
                        isnull(t4.sms_count_on_net,0)
FROM dbo.dumpfile_doroud t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.dumpfile139201 t2
 ON t2.msisdn = t1.msisdn
LEFT JOIN dumpfile139202 t3
 ON t3.msisdn = t1.msisdn
LEFT JOIN dumpfile139203 t4
 ON t4.msisdn = t1.msisdn
```

I don't think it's possible to make faster query, so you can try put indexes. I think you can create nonclustered index on column `msisdn` on all tables. Syntax:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_doroud_dumpfile139201  
    ON dbo.dumpfile139201(msisdn);
```

You can run SQL Management studio and turn on `display estimated execution plan` this sometimes gives good advices on creating indexes.

Comment: Try run each query and before query put `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` and after query put `SET STATISTICS TIME OFF`. And paste results for my query and yours. I'm think that this query could be faster with indexes. If you can put XML Plan...

Comment: It is faster than mine but still need to become faster. Please read the line that I added to my question. I am thinking of create 3 views and run query over them...

Answer (score 0):

Create a subquery to calculate the totals then join the table to it

```
UPDATE o 
SET o.sms_count_on_net = n.sms_count_on_net 
FROM 
dbo.dumpfile_doroud o
JOIN 
(SELECT 
d.msisdn, sms_count_on_net = (d1.sms_count_on_net+d2.sms_count_on_net+d3.sms_count_on_net)
FROM
dbo.dumpfile_doroud d
LEFT JOIN dbo.dumpfile139201 d1 ON d1.msisdn = d.msisdn
LEFT JOIN dbo.dumpfile139202 d2 ON d2.msisdn = d.msisdn
LEFT JOIN dbo.dumpfile139203 d3 ON d3.msisdn = d.msisdn) n
ON o.msisdn = n.msisdn
```

Note that if the value is missing from any of those tables the total will be null. That may or may not be what you want

Comment: If the daily tables are a lot smaller than the main one that's being updated then adding the critera
"WHERE 
d1.msisdn IS NOT NULL OR d2.msisdn IS NOT NULL OR d3.msisdn IS NOT NULL"  would eliminate the keys that aren't matched which might speed things up. The same goes for the other solution